# .delete and .renameTo not working Java

Tags: java, delete-file, file-rename

After running my program, the method doesnt really seem to work (delete and renameTo not working). The "tempuserlist" file is created but not renamed to "userlist". The "userlist" is not deleted nor is the "userFile". I have looked at multiple posts about similar issues but with no success. I have used import java.io.File;

```
static void DeleteUser (String[] username) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String response;
    System.out.print ("Are you sure you would like to delete this account/username (y/n)? ");
    response = stdin.readLine ();

    if (response.equals ("y") || response.equals ("Y") || response.equals ("yes") || response.equals ("Yes"))
    {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("G:\\MP3Folder\\userlist.txt"));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter ("G:\\MP3Folder\\tempuserlist.txt")));

        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)
        {
            if (username [0].equals (line))
            {
                continue;
            }
            writer.write (line);
            writer.newLine ();
        }
        writer.close ();
        reader.close ();

        File userFile = new File ("G:\\MP3Folder\\" + username [0] + ".txt");
        boolean success2 = userFile.delete ();

        File n = new File ("G:\\MP3Folder\\userlist.txt");
        boolean success1 = n.delete ();

        File o = new File ("G:\\MP3Folder\\tempuserlist.txt");
        boolean success = o.renameTo (n);

        System.out.println ("\nUser deleted.");

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("\nAccount deletion cancelled.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing that as `G:` is mapped drive then it is not available to the java process, try moving to a local drive or using its UNC

Comment: see http://www.coderanch.com/t/328372/java/java/Map-drive-access-Java-Application

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is correct. The same code works fine on my environment once I change the path. You need to change the path from G: to another local directory such as C: or D:

Comment: Unless of course G: is a local drive as well which it could very well be. The OP hasn't yet said either way.

Comment: Oh Yeah. Thanks @DevilsHnd for pointing that out. In case F: is a local directory as well then there has to be something wrong with the permissions. Maybe the user does not have permissions to delete or rename a file in G:\\MP3Folder

Answer (score 0):

The entire **DeleteUser()** method is rather suspect to begin with. I don't understand why you are passing a String Array (**username**) which is clearly only coded to delete one User File and that User would be the one contained within the very first element of the String Array (unless of course you're not telling us everything). The method declaration should be:

```
private static void deleteUser(String username) { .......... }
```

In any case...another thing, how in the world do we know that the **username.txt** file even exists as in:

```
File userFile = new File("G:\\MP3Folder\\" + username[0] + ".txt");
boolean success2 = userFile.delete ();
```

If it doesn't then a **FileNotFound Exception** is thrown and the remaining code will not play out. You perhaps should have:

```
File userFile = new File("G:\\MP3Folder\\" + username[0] + ".txt");
if (userFile.exists()) { userFile.delete(); }
```

No sense declaring boolean variables (like *success*, *success1*, and *success2*) since nothing is going to be done with them anyways.

Here is how I would create this method but then again...everyone does things a little differently:

```
private static void deleteUser(String userName) {
    String[] TheButtons = {"YES - Delete","NO - Don't Delete"};
    int res = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog (null, "Are you sure you would like to delete the account/username\n"
                                    + "titled: " + userName, "Delete User Account", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
                                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, TheButtons, TheButtons[1]);
    // NO selected
    if (res == 1) { 
        System.out.println ("\nAccount Deletion Cancelled.");
        return; 
    }

    try {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("G:\\MP3Folder\\userlist.txt")); 
             BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("G:\\MP3Folder\\tempuserlist.txt")))) {

            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
                if (userName.equals(line)) { continue; }
                writer.write (line);
                writer.newLine ();
            }
        }

        File userFile = new File ("G:\\MP3Folder\\" + userName + ".txt");
        if (userFile.exists()) { userFile.delete(); }

        File n = new File ("G:\\MP3Folder\\userlist.txt");
        File o = new File ("G:\\MP3Folder\\tempuserlist.txt");
        if (n.exists() && o.exists()) {
            n.delete();
            o.renameTo(n);
            System.out.println ("\nUser Deleted!");
        }
        else { 
            System.out.println ("\nError - File Not Found! - User Not Deleted!"); 
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println ("\nIO Exception Encountered!\n\n" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone and thanks to those who had immediate support and suggestions. I have fixed my issue after discovering a BufferReader and BufferWriter that were not closed after initializing them. With the program still using the username.txt, I was unable to delete or rename the files.

@DevilsHnd I first had a username array because this method was only a small part of my computer science final assignment(600 lines of code), and I need the array for other methods. I tried using boolean for a random reason hoping it would work. I did not need any verification for the "username.txt" if it existed, because it had to exist if my program ran in the first place. Sorry for the lack of insight and context, but thank you for the help.

@Crusauderpyro Thanks for trying out the code yourself. Although I was using an external drive (USB), the issue was not there as it is now functioning successfully. Thanks for the help.